# Login failed for user 'sa' when connecting to SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server instance (example/database111) using SQL Server Management Studio. I'm getting an error

> Login failed for user 'sa'

I've tried with Windows authentication as well as SQL Server authentication, and I'm still unable to connect.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

```
PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - Sertifika zinciri güvenilmeyen bir yetkili tarafından verildi.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): Sertifika zinciri güvenilmeyen bir yetkili tarafından verildi.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(PacketHandle packet, UInt32& sniError, Boolean canAccumulate, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean canAccumulate) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean canAccumulate) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsLogin(SqlLogin rec, FeatureExtension requestedFeatures, SessionData recoverySessionData, FederatedAuthenticationFeatureExtensionData fedAuthFeatureExtensionData, SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Login(ServerInfo server, TimeoutTimer timeout, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(DateTime giveUp)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> ClientConnectionId:c0514aaf-21fc-4fdf-a1de-9d73d55d687b
> Error Number:-2146893019,State:0,Class:20
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - Sertifika zinciri güvenilmeyen bir yetkili tarafından verildi.)

Code:

```
namespace DesingPatternsçChainOfRespobsibility.DAL
{
    public class Context:DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=example/database111;initial " +
                    "catalog=DesingPattern1;integrated security=true:");
        }

        public DbSet<CustomerProcess> customerProcesses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server with VS Code

Comment: [Connect to SQL Server when system administrators are locked out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: add trustservercertificate=true in the connection string which will then ignore the validation checks on the certificate and trust whatever certificate is presented. But then this is obviously insecure and not recommended )

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the breaking changes listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-true).

Check encrypt defaults to true,below three ways to mitigate this. Please notice that 2 and 3 are **unsafe**.

1. Install a valid certificate on the server. Note that this is an
   involved process and requires obtaining a certificate and ensuring
   it is signed by an authority trusted by the client.
2. If the server has a certificate, but it is not trusted by the
   client, then TrustServerCertificate=True to allow bypassing the
   normal trust mechanims.
3. Explicitly add Encrypt=False to the connection string.

Using #2 the code should look as:

```
namespace DesingPatternsçChainOfRespobsibility.DAL
{
    public class Context:DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=example/database111;initial " +
                    "catalog=DesingPattern1; TrustServerCertificate=True;integrated security=true:");
        }

        public DbSet<CustomerProcess> customerProcesses { get; set; }
    }
}
```